# JSF h:inputHidden managed bean value not updated in ajax call

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `h:inputHidden` field where it's value needs to be updated by an ajax call. I tried to use an `f:ajax` tag in the  `h:inputHidden` element but it didnt work (gave an error saying that you cannot used `<f:ajax>` in  `h:inputHidden` tag).

```
<h:panelGroup id="datesSelectPanel" styleClass="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="dateSelector" class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-1">
        <h:commandLink id="selectedDates" styleClass="btn default" style="margin: 90px 0 0 0;">
         <i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
         <p:ajax process="pickerHiddenPanel" onstart="loadSelectedDates()"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </div>
    <h:panelGroup id="dateSelectPanel" class="col-md-4">
      <h:panelGroup id="pickerHiddenPanel" styleClass="ulSelectedDatesHidden">
        <h:inputText id="sDates" value="#{managedBean.selectedDates}" style="display:none;" />
      </h:panelGroup>
      <ul style="width: 150px; height: 220px;" class="pull-left" id="ulSelectedDates"></ul>
```

DOM element ids

1. dateSelector - Is a multi date picker
2. selectedDates - Is a button that populates a list ulSelectedDates via javascript
3. sDates - Is the hidden filed that is supposed to store the date picker values to
   the managed bean.

So this is what happens,
I select multiple dates from a multi date picker (Bootstrap), and click a button to populate a box next to the calendar. When that is done the `#{managedBean.selectedDates}` bean value isnt updated as expected. I use Javascript to populate the list using function `loadSelectedDates()` which adds `<li>` elements to the `<ul>`.

I need to capture the date selection in the managed bean. Is there a way to solve this? Appreciate the help.

P.S : I used an `h:inputText` as suggested in another post that also didn't work, that is why you are seeing `h:inputText` rather than `h:inputHidden`

Answer (score 0):

Based on posted code:

- You didn't populate the value of `<h:inputText id="sDates"/>` in DOM
- `ConverterException` is thrown when converting value of `<h:inputText id="sDates"/>`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'Something else'?

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Your answer is now clearer.